Infinite dimensional fixed points and the Mandelbrot set bibliography question
For context: I am studying an electrodynamics problem which iterates recursively. I am doing everything numerically. The idea is (in the context of flat 1+1 dimensional spacetime with a scalar field):

Start with a (constant) background electric field of strength $\lambda$,

The electric field induces a charge density $\rho$,

The charge density creates an electric field $\int_0^x \rho$,

Update the electric field with the one generated in step 3,

Repeat steps 3-4 until some convergence is found (since the scalar field presents in theory screening behavior, this should converge).

If convergence is found, increase the background electric field strength $\lambda$.


There is apparently some critical $\lambda$ for which the problem presents some instabilities. To deal with this, the update law for the electric field at the step k looks something like this:
$$
E_{k+1}(x) = c E_k(x) + (1-c) ( \lambda + \int _0^x \rho(x') dx' ), 0 < c \lesssim 1
$$
so that the updates are not done so "violently" and they relax more from one to the other.
To finish the context, this is what the functions I am looking at look like

(This is actually the electric potential associated with the induced electric field i.e. its antiderivative, but that is not relevant). I do not know why, but as the iterations increase and $\lambda$ increases, the shape of the function does not change. Therefore, to visualize the problem better, I take advantage of this and just look at the function at x=1.
This was just context to show how I check for solutions. What I have found, is that this convergence is very weird. sometimes it will just converge relatively fast

But some other times, it "converges" to two different values

This reminds me of the Mandelbrot set,

in which the main cardioid (labeled 1) is the values of c in the update law $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$ for which the sequence as $n\to \infty$ converges to a single value. However, in the region labeled 2, the sequence does not converge, but it has a periodicity 2, i.e. both $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_{2n+1}$ exist and are finite, but are different. The similarity with my problem is that I am sampling the parameter space with $\lambda$ and for some $\lambda$ and this update law the problem has a single convergent value (since I am studying functions, this value belongs to some infinite dimensional space) and for some other the problem converges to two (or actually more) different values.
All this is very far away from my field of "expertise", so I am not even sure how to correctly pose the question.
Is there any branch of mathematics that studies this kind of problem? Where can I look into this?
